# How do I save formattet text in MySQL | Django

Tags: mysql, django, codeigniter, django-models

In Django we have a model field called `TextField`. and A simple html page which have a tag `<textarea id="textarea" cols="10" rows="5" wrap="off"></textarea>`

I write Python code in this area and press submit button so that it will be saved in DB. The problem is when I retrieve back from DB it looses its formatting. I will have to show end user as the same format as he entered.

as this can be seen here http://ideone.com/B5AUiQ. I'm not sure about how any other sites like codeacademy, spoj, topcoder, codechef, codepad etc uses this and what could be the best solution.

considering Django and in general both

I found these threads but not clearly shows how to do it in general

[How to store formatted text in MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574646/how-to-store-formatted-text-in-mysql-table)

[How to safely insert code in mySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759035/how-to-safely-insert-code-in-mysql-database)

[How can I store PHP code inside of a mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073836/how-can-i-store-php-code-inside-of-a-mysql-table)

Comment: This is probably more a case of how you are actually parsing the text to be stored in the db rather than the db itself... all a database would see is a `\t` or similar for tabs etc

Comment: What do you mean with "formated" ? Is it HTML formatting ? Are you using a editor like tinymce for it ?

Comment: Look into javascript libraries for code highlighting. This way you can save and render plain text in your Django project and let the JS handle the rest.